# Change the sign of the number in the pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, series

How to change the sign in the series, if I have:

> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13

and need to get:

> 1, 2, 3, -4, -5, -6, 8, 9, 10, -11, -12, -13

I need to be able to set the period (now it is equal to 3) and the index from which the function starts (now it is equal to 3).

For example, if I specify 2 as the index, I get

> 1, 2, -3, -4, -5, 6, 8, 9, -10, -11, -12, 13

I need to apply this function sequentially to each column, since applying to the entire DataFrame leads to a memory error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with integer division by (`//`) and modulo (`%`) for boolean mask:

```
s = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13])

N = 3
#if default RangeIndex
m = (s.index // N) % 2 == 1
#general index
#m = (np.arange(len(s.index)) // N) % 2 == 1
s = pd.Series(np.where(m, -s, s))
print (s)
0      1
1      2
2      3
3     -4
4     -5
5     -6
6      7
7      8
8      9
9    -10
10   -11
11   -12
12    13
dtype: int64
```

EDIT:

```
N = 3
M = 1
m = np.concatenate([np.repeat(False, M), 
                   (np.arange(len(s.index) - M) // N) % 2 == 0])

s = pd.Series(np.where(m, -s, s))
print (s)
0      1
1     -2
2     -3
3     -4
4      5
5      6
6      7
7     -8
8     -9
9    -10
10    11
11    12
12    13
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thank you, your code is very good. I would like to be able to set the index from which the function begins, as well as the ability to apply it to each column sequentially.

Comment: @hyper - Sorry, not understand. If `s = pd.Series([8,9,1])` then need change index `[0,1,2]` to starting by some number like `M = 5` for index `[5,6,7]` ? Or something else?

Comment: If `s = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14])` and `N=3`  
and I want to change the sign for example from the fifth member of the series, then I will get `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, -6, -7, -8, 9, 10, 11, -12, -13, -14`

Comment: @hyper - So `M=5` ? Is always M > N, here `5>3` ?

Comment: no with M = 1 and N=3 `1, -2, -3, -4, 5, 6, 7, -8, -9, -10, 11, 12, 13, -14`